Trace Network with multiple starting and ending points belonging to different groups
I'm new to using ArcGIS (Pro Advanced 3.0.3 version) and I have a route and 2 groups of points where 1 group will connect to the closest point of the 2nd group. I created a Trace Network layer and enabled network topology where the dirty areas are not going away. I am not sure any article on the net might help with it (searched a lot but to no avail). Validate button just does not work. The main question I have is how to connect these 2 groups of points using 'Shortest Path' but instead of selecting the starting points manually, I want to give an input of what the starting points will be for it to choose from.
How can I resolve the issue where the dirty areas do not go away and the shortest path can selected between 2 points. Also, the points that I have displayed do not get selected in the Trace Locations Starting point for some awkward reason. This has been exhausting!
Dirty Area example:

